# Is there a Win32 API to add double quotes in a string?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm searching for a possible Win32 API to add double quotes in a string variable, similar to [`AnsiQuotedStr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.AnsiQuotedStr) of Delphi/C++Builder, where these variable strings are paths respectively, like:

- *C:\Program Files (x86)\file1.exe* - **strvar1**
- *C:\Program Files (x86)\file2.exe* - **strvar2**

and this will be sent to a VBScript (via [`ShellExecute()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) *lpParameters*) that receives/process these args.

Comment: Please explain more about what you're trying to do.  Adding double quotes to a string is no different to adding any _other_ character to a string.  Perhaps you're actually asking how to write a string literal that contains a double-quote.  For that, simply _escape_ the character: _i.e._ `\"`

Comment: If you're using VBScript, why not use VBScript's own `Replace( str, """", """""" )` ?

Comment: If it's specifically for paths, you could use PathQuoteSpaces  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathquotespacesw

Comment: @dai Because the VBScript runs *after* `ShellExecute` has already failed to parse the strings.

Comment: @SimonMourier, thank you very much. `PathQuoteSpaces`, is a smart solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AnsiQuotedStr()` wraps a string in quotes, and doubles up any quotes already in the string. There is no Win32 API that is exactly like that. The closest would be  [`PathQuoteSpaces()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathquotespacesw), which wraps a string in quotes if it contains any space characters. Not the same thing.

But, this is easy to implement manually, especially when using `std::string`, eg:

```cpp
std::string AddQuotes(std::string S)
{
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    while ((pos = S.find('"', pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        S.insert(pos, 1, '"');
        pos += 2;
    }
    return '"' + S + '"';
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/yqRB6r)

Alternatively, without invoking potentially many memory reallocations:

```cpp
std::string AddQuotes(const std::string &S)
{
    auto start = S.begin(), end = S.end();
    size_t num = std::count(start, end, '"');
    std::string res;
    res.reserve(S.size() + num + 2);
    res.push_back('"');
    if (num != 0) {
        auto curr = std::find(start, end, '"');
        do {
            ++curr;
            res.insert(res.end(), start, curr);
            res.push_back('"');
            start = curr;
            curr = std::find(start, end, '"');
        }
        while (curr != end);
        res.insert(res.end(), start, end);
    }
    res.push_back('"');
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/1aKvM9)

Comment: I'd write a split that generates string views on a delimiter.  Then `r="\""+piece;`, and terminate with a quote.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont maybe you don't realize what `AnsiQuotedStr()` actually does. Not only does it append a quote char at the begin and end of the string, but it also doubles any quote chars inside of the string.

Comment: I do. `for i in split(str, '"') r+= '"'+i; r+='"'` does that for reasonable values of split.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont that still does not produce the right output. If `str` is empty, the result is `"` instead of `""`. And if `str` is like `hi"there`, the result is `"hi"there"` instead of `"hi""there"`, unless `split()` includes the delimiter in the sub-views (ie, `hi"`, `there`), which is not typical for a delimiter-splitting function.

Comment: Yes; it must return one empty view on the empty string.  And include delimiters.  It delimites on "gap before quote or end of string".